# Reference to System.Windows.Forms in .net7.0 class library project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, class-library

I need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms in class library project written in .net7.0 that will be distributed in NuGet for my young students.
How can this be done?
The class that I want to add to the project:

```
public class DebugApp
{
   Form form;
   TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
   Button button = new Button();
   Label label = new Label();
   Panel panel = new Panel();
   List<string> data = new List<string>();
   .....
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewindowsforms

Comment: I add that line but it's not working, Maybe something else is missingץ

Answer (score -1):

I Create Windows Forms Project, change it to class library in project properties, delete Form1 and Program.cs and it's working.